# Cronjob to run every 30 minutes

Tags: cron

I want to set a cronjob entry that runs a script every 30 minutes from 9:00 to 18:00 but I do not want it to run at 18:30. The script should run for the first time at 9:00 and for the last time at 18:00. Is this possible?

Comment: The question was [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248835/cronjob-to-run-every-30-minutes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
0,30 9-18 * * * /path_to_script
```

However, the above will run at 18:30.  So, you're best bet is to have a separate job to handle 18:00.  So:

```
0,30 9-17 * * * /path_to_script
0 18 * * * /path_to_script
```

Also, [Cron job generators](http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/) are awesome.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: I was wishing to accomplish this in a single line but I later learned that it was not possible only using cron. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Or do an extra test before firing the script. In the example below I test if current  is less than 1815.

```
 0,30 9-18 * * * [ $(date +\%H\%M) -le 1815 ] && /path_to_script
```